# What is the real visitors/day and visitors per day?

Tags: discussion, support

From the [Database Administrators Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4260/database-administrators) it says that there are 132 visits/day, but the [site itself](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) lists 991 visitors/day in the Site Stats.  It would seem that visits/day would be higher than visitors/day.  The visits/day on Area 51 was zero before the public beta started, which was understandable ([and appears common](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74311/0-visits-per-day)), but it seems like it should be higher now.  Should we assume these stats are not accurate until the evaluation wording is added (Excellent, Okay, Worrying)?

Comment: Is one "uniques" and the other "actuals"?

Comment: This might actually be better answered on MSO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4260/database-administrators) is using the **median over the last 14 days**.  This site hasn't been in existence for 14 days, so there are a few days with a value of 0 that are bringing down the numbers a significant.

The formula for what [the site itself says](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) is described by Kevin in [an answer on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64863/how-is-views-day-calculated/64891#64891).

> Now, a site's views_per_day is calculated as follows:
>
> - Vn = sum of view counts of all questions created after the site (regardless of where they were created originally)
> - F(q) = (q's view count) * (number of days the site has existed) / (number of days q has existed)
> - Vu = sum of F(q) for all questions created before the site
> - views_per_day = (Vn + Vu) / (number of days the site has existed)